# Jquery for each skips URL routing

Tags: jquery

I am getting id of user from database, then I am running for each loop get each users id and inside for each loop I am creating URL of specific user and running that url using `location.href` in for each loop, but instead of running that url for each user it runs only once.

```
jqueryarray.forEach(function(jqueryarray) {

    setTimeout(function(){
      location.href="/project/filedownload/"+jqueryarray;
    }, 1000);
});
```

Kindly suggest me where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try like to do it this:

```
var jqueryarray=[1,2,3]; 

jqueryarray.forEach(function(id) { 

(function(i){ 
   setTimeout(function(){ 
       window.open("/project/filedownload/"+i); }, 1000);
})(id); 

});
```

Comment: `var jqueryarray=[1,2,3];`
`jqueryarray.forEach(function(id) {
  (function(i){
    setTimeout(function(){
      window.open("/project/filedownload/"+i); 
    }, 1000);})(id);
});`

Comment: try like this. but browser blocks opening tabs and enelable it.